# "Permission denied" while running a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I'm new to linux, coding and generally computer sciences. I am trying to run a bash script, but I get this error:

```
./fastalign_train.sh: line 5: /forward.align: Permission denied
./fastalign_train.sh: line 6: /reverse.align: Permission denied
```

There are two txt files (forward.align and reverse.align):
ls -l result:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tara tara      72 Feb 12 08:05 reverse.align
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tara tara      76 Feb 12 08:05 forward.align
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tara tara 2089888 Feb 11 03:00 fast_align
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tara tara     242 Feb 11 12:32 fastalign_train.sh
```

Any idea? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is in the filename shown: `/forward.align`

This implies that you try to write to `/forward.align`, which is in the root (`/`) of the file system. Users do not have write permissions there.

Replace `/forward.align` with either `./forward.align` or `forward.align`., and same for `/reverse.align`, and it should work.

Comment: Yes, it runs now but there is no output...like nothing happens. this is the main line of my bash code:

${FASTALIGN}/fast_align -i $1 -d -o -v -p $2/fwd_params > $2./forward.align 2>$2./fwd_err

Comment: Post a new question if you have a new question. If you want help debugging, include all of your script.